# excel plot against a date time x series

Tags: excel

Why does Excel ignore the time component of datetime values in a chart. For example, the following data :

```
10/10/2010 9:30   1 
10/10/2010 9:40   2
10/10/2010 9:50   3
10/10/2010 10:00  4 
10/10/2010 10:10  5
10/10/2010 10:20  6
```

excel plots it all values on a same x-value 10/10/2010.
If I format the values as time, it works fine. How do I tell excel to display datetime and interpret it as datetime not date..

Answer (score 36):

Try using an X-Y Scatter graph with datetime formatted as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.

This provides a reasonable graph for me (using Excel 2010).

[image: Excel Datetime XY Scatter]

Comment: Can u give a small example as well... Would certainly help...

Comment: Make sure your "datetime" column is a real Excel date, like from the =DATEVALUE formula. A custom "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" format will not work. (Also in Excel 2010)

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question, but I was struggling to do this with a time period over 2 hours, so this might help someone. Also, several of the answers don't actually plot against time, giving equal space whatever the duration.

Firstly, as @jameswarren says, use a scatter graph. Then right-click the horizontal axis and choose *Format Axis*.

Under Number, select *Time*, and at this point you may find your scale goes a bit crazy, because it chooses to scale the axis by days. So go back to Axis Options and select *Fixed* for the Minimum, Maximum and Major unit scales.

To set the unit to hours, type in 1/24 = **0.0416667** (I used half that to get half-hourly increments).
To make this start at a round number, multiply it by your preferred number of hours and type that into the Minimum box. In my case 08:00 = **0.333333**

[image: graph showing plot against time on x-axis]

Comment: In newer version of excel (2016 in my case) decimals are rounded up to 1.

Answer (score 19):

There is one way to do this, as long as you have regular time intervals between all your date-time values - make the x-axis consider the values as text.

> > in Excel 2007, click on the chart - Go to the layout menu (contextual menu on clicking on the chart) , choose the option **Axes->Primary Horizontal Axes-> More Horizontal Axes Options**
> >     Under **Axis Type**, choose "**Text Axis**"

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes regular time intervals. If you have intervals of varying length, this approach will distort your data (each entry is given equal width on the axis).

Comment: I can't find that "Text axis" option in the newer Excels with the graph options in the pane on the right

Answer (score 7):

That was much more painful than it ought to have been.

It turns out there are two concepts, the format of the data and the format of the axis. You need to format the data series as a time, then you format the graph's display axis as date and time.

### Graph your data

Highlight all columns and insert your graph

[image: First graph your data]

### Format datetime cells

Select the column, right click, format cells. Select time so that the data is in time format.

[image: Format the cells]

### Now format the axis

Now right click on the axis text and change it to display whatever format you want

[image: Format axis as custom date]

Answer (score 3):

[excel 2010] separate the date and time into separate columns and select both as X-Axis and data as graph series
see http://www.79783.mrsite.com/USERIMAGES/horizontal_axis_date_and_time2.xlsx

Comment: You shouldn't include external files, because if they will removed, the answer will be useless. Please create pictures, add information and description on how to achieve the result.

Comment: i would have, but it said i dont have enough rep to publish them. so till then the only way is to add a link

Comment: Make an edit with a link to the picture and I will add it.

Comment: nearly 5 years later and the external file is _still_ available!

Comment: external file not available anymore.

Comment: Mirror: https://web.archive.org/web/20160306155649/http://79783.mrsite.com/userimages/horizontal_axis_date_and_time2.xlsx

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify TimeSeries in Excel to be plotted. 
Have a look at [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/excel-time-series-chart.php)

[image: Plotting Time Series]

Comment: I don't see this option in my format axis unfortunately. I am using Excel 2010. thanks

Comment: I've tried line plot, x-y scatter plot, etc but nothing works. Line plot doesn't understand datetime. Scatter plot messes up start and end points. It starts time from 0:00:00. I don't want to change auto to manual points as I am using this as a template. Just need a simple solution

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy workaround for this problem

What you need to do, is format your dates as DD/MM/YYYY (or whichever way around you like)

Insert a column next to the time and date columns, put a formula in this column that adds them together. e.g. =A5+B5.

Format this inserted column into DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss which can be found in the custom category on the formatting section

Plot a scatter graph

Badabing badaboom

If you are unhappy with this workaround, learn to use GNUplot :)